# How to get Flutter app to be available for iCloud backup

Tags: ios, flutter, icloud, flutter-hive

I'm building a mobile app with flutter that uses Hive to save user data. I'd like my iOS app to back up all this data in the user's iCloud backup. I have my app published and running on a real device. However, when I go to Settings -> [MY NAME] -> iCloud, I don't see my app in the list of "apps using iCloud". My research seems to indicate that anything in the app's documents folder will be automatically backed up. I believe that all my Hive boxes are stored in this documents folder. If they are, what could casue my phone to not allow me to back up the data from my app? If Hive doesn't use the documents folder, how do I change that?

Comment: have you looked at https://pub.dev/packages/icloud_storage

Comment: Yes I did. On that page it says "Documents and other data that is user-generated and stored in the <Application_Home>/Documents directory can be automatically backed up by iCloud on iOS devices, if the iCloud Backup setting is turned on."

My iCloud Backup setting is turned on, yet my data is not being automatically uploaded. My question is asking why this automatic update isn't happening.

Comment: Have you tried doing everything on the install page... there's a lot of settings that must be enabled and set properly?  Can you try the code of the examples or the tests to see if they work in your setup?